# Vertical Order Traversal of B-Tree -> Error "Line 924: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)"

Tags: c++, linux, data-structures, binary-tree

I am getting runtime error while running the following code on leetcode.The problem involves finding the Vertical Traversal of a binary Tree.

I am getting the following error:

> Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator>' (stl_vector.h) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9

Problem link - https://leetcode.com/problems/vertical-order-traversal-of-a-binary-tree/

My Code :

```
/**
* Definition for a binary tree node.
* struct TreeNode {
*     int val;
*     TreeNode *left;
*     TreeNode *right;
*     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
*     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
*     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
* };
*/
class Solution {
public:
vector<vector<int>> verticalTraversal(TreeNode* root) 
{
    
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    
    map<int, vector<int>> mp;
    
    if(root == NULL)
        return ans;
    
    queue<pair<TreeNode* , int>> q;
    q.push({root,0});
    
     
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        auto p= q.front();
        TreeNode *curr = p.first;
        int hd=  p.second;
        q.pop();
        
        
        if(root->left != NULL)
        {
            q.push({root->left, hd-1});
        }
        
        if(root -> right != NULL)
        {
            q.push({root->right, hd+1});
        }
        ans[hd].push_back(curr->val);
    }
    
    return ans;
}
};
```

Comment: `ans[hd].push_back(curr->val);` is the problem. `ans` is an empty `vector`, you cannot index it. You have to push something to it, before you access it. You only push to the inner `vector`.

Comment: @mch , Can you suggest a correction in my code ? I am not sure about the right way to correct it.

Comment: `if (ans.size() < hd + 1) ans.resize(hd + 1);` before this line should do the job. This will create the required elements for `ans`, so that you can add something to `ans[hd]`.

Comment: """""" On doing that, I am getting a new error :( """""" Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x603000000160 overflowed to 0x603000000148 (stl_vector.h) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34